# ES6 object assign partial items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, assign

I have a list of js objects like:

```
actualVal = [{pId: a1, pVal: b1}, {pId: a2, pVal: b2}, ....]
```

This I'm getting passed to my function and I'm getting it to my reference using ES6 as:

```
let { myVal } = actualVal;
```

This gives me something like:

```
myVal = [{pId: a1, pVal: b1}, {pId: a2, pVal: b2}, ....]
```

Is there a way in ES6 to get this as:

```
myVal = [{id: a1, val: b1}, {id: a2, val: b2}, ....]
```

I can loop through the array to do this, but is there a way to map this without iterating? Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks everyone for the answers. So which one is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not, but lodash's `mapKeys` function can help do this for you. Also, `let { myVal } = actualVal` will not create a copy of your array if that's what you're thinking, so you'll need to handle that another way anyway.

```
actualVal = [{pId: a1, pVal: b1}, {pId: a2, pVal: b2}, ....]
let newArr = actualVal.map((e, i) => {
  return _.mapKeys(e, function (val, key) {
    if (key === 'pId')
      return 'id'
    else if 
      // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to iterate over your array like this

```
myVal.map( val => {return {id: val.pId, val: val.pVal}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Only using array map:

```
myVal = actualVal.map(function(obj) {
    return {
        id: obj.pId,
        val: obj.pVal
    };
});
```

Comment: Array map is implemented with native code, that allow to perform optimization and a much faster code than just a JS loop (supposing that both implementations are corrects and optimal).